# Showing Image from URL in the image view is showing blurred(not clear) image?

Tags: android

I am fetching url from the array-list and showing it in the image view but the image is not cleared or you say its blurred. since the image coming from the URL is high-defination and after watching it its dimension is same as high definition.

```
String image_url = rowItem.getMediaUrl();// url of image



                if (image_url != null && image_url.length() > 0)


                    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, imageViewpostimage);
                   // showing image in the imageview (imageViewpostimage)
```

Image view code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/UserPostImage"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_photo" />
```

i have done imageview all type like "fill parent","wrap-content".,"match-parent". but always i am getting blurred image in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scaletype property. I believe 'fitXY' will be most appropriate.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/UserPostImage"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_photo" />
```

See this link for more scaling options [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: @Ghost Hacker was this answer useful? :)